# duScroll no funciona correctamente AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estoy haciendo uso de un herramienta que nos ofrece angular que es `Angular-scroll` donde tengo una función que ejecuta un scroll hacia arriba, pero no he tratado de conseguirlo, por favor alguna solución?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/1.0.2/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 120vh;">EXAMPLE</div>
  
  <footer>
    <button ng-click="scrollToTop()">To the top!</button>
  </footer>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['duScroll']).
  controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document){

    $scope.scrollToTop = function() {
      $document.duScrollTop();
    };

  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El error `unhandle rejection` hay forma de que puedas mostrar un ejemplo emulando el error? No puedo reproducirlo.

Comment: @Einer lo intentare reproducir editando mi pregunta !! dame momento,

Comment: @Einer aun no intento reproducirlo, el error solo me sale en mi proyecto...Algo estoy haciendo mal, estuve haciendo varios ejemplos y funciona correctamente no se que estoy haciendo de diferente, estaré comentando si algo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[La funcion duScrollTop tiene un bug y al parecer no se ha corregido](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll/pull/184). Utiliza el metodo `scrollToElement` enviandole el elemento de hasta donde quieres el scroll, el padding, y la duracion en milisegundos:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/1.0.2/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id='example' style="width: 100%; height: 120vh;">EXAMPLE</div>
  
  <footer>
    <button ng-click="scrollToTop()">To the top!</button>
  </footer>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['duScroll']).
  controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document){

    $scope.scrollToTop = function() {
      var example = angular.element(document.getElementById('example'));
      
      $document.scrollToElement(example,0, 2000);
    };

  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok @Einer con solo decirme que tiene un bug me basta jeje gracias.

Comment: Recuerda aceptarla si era la respuesta que buscabas.

Comment: Me esta ocurriendo un error, trato de solucionarlo.

Comment: Si es relacionado a la pregunta, puedes compartilo.

Comment: Revisa una respuesta amigo donde explico el error que me sale.

Comment: podemos tener una charla en una sala para contarte algo bro? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que parece que la función  `duScrollTop()` tiene un bug puedes utilizar la función `duScrollTo()`

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/1.0.2/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 120vh;">EXAMPLE</div>
  
  <footer>
    <button ng-click="scrollToTop()">To the top!</button>
  </footer>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['duScroll']).
  controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document){

    $scope.scrollToTop = function() {
      $document.duScrollTo();
    };

  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```